# Is there a name for era(s) between Old Republic in KOTOR and Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

Certain eras in TGFFA are well defined (both in-universe, as well as out-of-universe in terms of publishing) and are named, e.g. Old Republic era (KOTOR time), Clone Wars era, New Republic era, etc...

Are there named eras between the time of Old Republic described in KOTOR and Old Republic MMO; and Clone Wars era? If so, what bundles of EU material cover them (the way NJO books cover that era, or Legacy and Downfall books the Legacy era?)

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this as too broad. The MMO [took place over 3000 years before the events of the movies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic) so there is too much to cover in an answer to this question. (BTW, the Republic stopped being the *Old* Republic when the Empire was created. It's no longer canonical, but after the events of the movies there was supposed to be a *New* Republic after the fall of the Empire.)

Comment: I'm not asking for a synposis, I'm asking for material that covers this time, the three questions in bulletpoints, are what I'm specifically looking as answers. What is SFF.SE.?

Comment: @Aaronepower: SFF.SE is this site (Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange) — welcome!

Comment: Even if you're only looking for material (books, games, etc.?) there's a lot of that in 3000 "years" of events in the *Star Wars* universe. Also, if you have multiple questions they should be split up rather than posted all in one question.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite SFF.SE sounds like a Star Wars time period, honestly.

Comment: @Null Those three are really just one lines, like what you answered.

Comment: Check here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history

Comment: (1) I re-wrote the question to be answerable and not too broad. Please VTRO. (2) @Aaronepower, I edited out tangential but **very interesting** subquestion of when "Old Republic" stopped being "old". Please post as a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_galactic_history), the time period between *Knights of The Old Republic* and *The Phantom Menace* overlaps with four broad periods of Galactic History:

### Old Sith Wars: 4000 BBY<sup>1</sup> - 3950 BBY

This period is dominated by conflicts with various Sith Lords (hence the name), and opens with the events of the [*Tales of the Jedi*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Tales_of_the_Jedi) comic series. *Knights of the Old Republic* picks up at the tail end of this period, with the main story of the first game starting in  3956 BBY.

- The [*Knights of the Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic) video game and its [sequel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords)
- The [*Knights of the Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_(comics)) comic series takes place before the video games, near the end of the Mandalorian Wars. The sequel miniseries [*Knights of the Old Republic: War*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic:_War) is also during this period
- Two eBooks in the *Lost Tribe of the Sith* series take place in this era: [*Purgatory*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Purgatory) and [*Sentinel*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Sentinel)

### Inter-Sith Wars Period: 3950 BBY - 2000 BBY

The events of *SW:TOR* occur entirely within this period; although we don't know *exactly* when the game will end, it's probably safe to assume that it won't last for two thousand years. The most recent *TOR* expansion, [*Shadow of Revan*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic:_Shadow_of_Revan), takes place in 3640 BBY.

There's very little fiction that takes place during this period; most of the information we have on it comes from [*The Essential Atlas*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas), which was intended to be a definitive source for planetary information. Some information can also be found in material related to *The Old Republic* MMO, especially in-game codex entries.

- [*The Old Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic_(novel_series)) prose series takes place at the end of this period, as does [*The Old Republic* comic series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic_(comics))
- Three of the eBooks in the *Lost Tribe of the Sith* series take place post-*TOR*: [*Pantheon*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Pantheon), [*Secrets*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Secrets), and [*Pandemonium*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Pandemonium). The comic miniseries [*Lost Tribe of the Sith: Spiral*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Spiral) also takes place in this period. This series was a tie-in to the [*Fate of the Jedi*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_of_the_Jedi) series, which takes place in the Legacy period

### Draggulch Period: 2000 BBY - *c.* 1000 BBY

This period coincides almost entirely with the [New Sith Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/New_Sith_Wars), and the last century of this period is sometimes called the [Republic Dark Age](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_Dark_Age).

Once again, there's very little fiction set in this period. Most information comes from Essential guides and RPG sourcebooks.

- *Knight Errant*, the [novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_Errant_(novel)) and the [comic series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knight_Errant)
- The first novel in the Darth Bane Trilogy, [*Path of Destruction*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane:_Path_of_Destruction)

### Post-Ruusan Period: *c.* 1000 BBY - 19 BBY

Also sometimes called the [Great Peace of the Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Peace_of_the_Republic), Wookieepedia technically calls this the "Fall of the Republic/Rise of the Empire Period." In-universe, this period begins with the [Ruusan Reformation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ruusan_Reformation), a structural reorganization of the Jedi Order, and the Republic itself to a lesser extent, so significant that it became year 0 in the (in-universe) Galactic calendar. The first 700 or so years of this period is also called the [Golden Age of the Old Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Age_of_the_Old_Republic).

- The Darth Bane Trilogy concludes in this era
- [*Star Wars: Jedi*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_(2011_series)), a comic book series about Qui-Gon Jinn's relationship with his first apprentice
- [*Legacy of the Jedi*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Jedi) and it's sequel, [*Secrets of the Jedi*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Secrets_of_the_Jedi), mostly take place in this period. The last section of each book is set during the Clone Wars
- [*Jedi Council: Acts of War*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Council:_Acts_of_War), a comic book miniseries set shortly before *Phantom Menace*
- The [*Jedi Apprentice*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Apprentice) series, a series of 18 "young reader" novels detailing Obi-Wan Kenobi's apprenticeship under Qui-Gon Jinn
- [*Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan: The Autorient Express*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_and_Obi-Wan:_The_Aurorient_Express) and [*Last Stand on Ord Mantell*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_and_Obi-Wan:_Last_Stand_on_Ord_Mantell)
- There were several works focused on the exploits of Darth Maul, including the novels [*Shadow Hunter*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Maul:_Shadow_Hunter) and [*Lockdown*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Maul:_Lockdown), and the [*Darth Maul*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul) comic series
- The [*Episode I Adventures*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_I_Adventures) series of youth novels
- The [*Star Wars: Republic*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic) comics begin in 33 BBY, and carry through until shortly after the events of *Revenge of the Sith*
- The [*Jedi Quest*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Quest) series, a young reader's series in the style of *Jedi Apprentice*; these books document Anakin Skywalker's early training

The above lists of works are incomplete by design. If you're interested in a more complete list of works, [Wookieepedia has a helpful timeline of Legends media](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_media)

---

<sup>1</sup> Dates in Legends are typically based around the Battle of Yavin, the climactic battle in *A New Hope*, which is 0 ABY; BBY and ABY mean exactly what you'd expect them to

Comment: You should add the Knights of the Old Republic comic series as well. It fits within the Sith Wars period.

Comment: @Omegacron Fair enough; I guess it doesn't hurt to discuss the tail end of the Old Sith Wars period

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about named eras, but there's the battle of Ruusan/rise of Darth Bane, covered in the Darth Bane trilogy. It occurs 1000 years before the clone wars, so 2000 after the period covered in the Old Republic game. Introduces the sith 'rule of two', setting the stage somewhat for Sidious' rise to power

Answer (score 0):

There is virtually no material covering the events between the *end* of Star Wars: The Old Republic and the beginning of the Darth Bane trilogy. The event we know about between the [Galactic War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_War) and the [New Sith Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/New_Sith_Wars) (which is the war that is featured in the Darth Bane trilogy) is referred to as the [Darth Desolous conflict](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Desolous_conflict).

[image: Darth Desolous]

However, not only is this no longer considered canon due to the legends rebrand, it was also very flimsy from its inception. Its only reference is a databank entry in the Wii and Playstation 2 versions of The Force Unleashed.

However, the New Sith Wars mark the transition period between what (in legends material) is considered the [Old Republic era](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Republic_era) and what is called the [Rise of the Empire era](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Empire_era).

A reference to mark the transition (more of a discrete event) is the [Ruusan Reformation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ruusan_Reformation). This is the legends explanation to Chancellor Palpatine's remarks in Episode II.

> "I will not let this Republic that has stood for a thousand years be split in two. My negotiations will not fail." - Chancellor Palpatine